# Остановка выполнения потока

Tags: многопоточность, swing

Подскажите, имеется форма

```
public class MainFrame extends JFrame {
    private int colThread=0;
    MainThread mt=new MainThread("Поток - 1");

    public MainFrame()  
    {
        setSize(300,300);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel jp = new JPanel();
        JButton jb=new JButton("Запустить поток");
        jb.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                jb.setText("Перезапустить поток");
                colThread = colThread + 1;
                if (!mt.isInterrupted())
                {
                    mt.interrupt();
                }
                mt.start();             
            }           
        });
        jp.add(jb);
        add(jp);
    }
}
```

имеется класс потока:

```
public class MainThread extends Thread{
    private int summ;
    private String threadName;

    public MainThread(String threadName)
    {
        this.threadName = threadName;
    }   

    @Override
    public void run() {
        summ = 0;
        while(true)
        {
            summ = summ +1;
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println(this.threadName + " " + summ);
        }
    }

}
```

и основной класс:

```
public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MainFrame mf = new MainFrame();
        mf.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Вопрос заключается в том, каким образом при нажатии на кнопку можно перезапустить выполнение потока. При выполнении программы в этом виде возникает ошибка, но это и понятно, поток ведь работает, не понятно почему не работает interrupt()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Согласно описания Thread один поток нельзя запускать дважды, решить задачу можно путем применения Runnable, только необходимо учесть, что если поток цикличен, то необходимо его остановить иначе будет одновременно два потока

```
public class MainFrame extends JFrame {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int colThread=0;
    MainThread mt=new MainThread("Поток - 1");
    Thread tr = null;

    public MainFrame()  
    {
        setSize(300,300);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel jp = new JPanel();
        JButton jb=new JButton("Запустить поток");
        jb.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

                jb.setText("Перезапустить поток");
                colThread = colThread + 1;
                if (tr!=null &&!tr.isInterrupted())
                {
                    tr.interrupt();
                }
                tr = new Thread(mt);
                tr.start();             
            }           
        });
        jp.add(jb);
        add(jp);
    }
}
```